# Nothing Happens When Run "truffle test" in terminal

Tags: truffle-test

When I try to run "truffle test" on any contract, nothing happens in the terminal, it just waits as if it's loading or something. I have tried this on the simplest of contracts. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi CyberDisc0! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Please include in the question enough details to reproduce the problem. The contracts involved, the configuration, the tests and migration files, a link to a github repo should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had to use v12 of nodejs for truffle, it apparently isn't compatible with newer versions